# Waiting for User login before executing code that uses User-Information

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my Android-Application and using Auth and Realtime-DB. I want to set a value in the Database when I interact with the UI (Open Fragment when clicking item in BottomNavigationActivity), but I want the user to be Logged in before the Database gets accessed. I run the following code when my Fragment is initalized:

```
public static void setFoods(ArrayList<FoodItem> foods){
    if(user != null){
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("users/" + user.getUid() + "/foods");
        reference.setValue(foods);
    }
}
```

The  `!= null` check makes sure that the User is logged in. But i want it to execute *when* the `user` variable changes, and not have to reopen the Fragment to load the list once the user is Logged in.

If anybody could tell me how you execute code once the value changes, I would be very happy. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you mean something like this:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            Log.d(getSubClassTAG(), "onAuthStateChanged: singed in: " + user.getUid());
        } else {
            Log.d(getSubClassTAG(), "onAuthStateChanged: signed out: ");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That code would execute as soon as i log in, but not when the fragment gets is loading. Im using that already to set the user variable, and this is not the answer to my question. Thanks anyways

Comment: So I implemented a Loading-Screen for my app and used this method. So this is essentially the solution to my problem!